# How do I create a desktop shortcut in Fedora 23?

Tags: fedora

There is no right-click option to create a shortcut whether I click on the desktop or application's icon in the activities menu. I created a `.desktop` file, made it executable, and moved it to `~/Desktop`, but there is no shortcut on the desktop. What should I do?

Comment: First try making the desktop file executable. If it fails, please consider adding which desktop environment do you use - this is specific for each of them. I think Fedora ships with all of the following: LXDE, Xfce, Gnome3, KDE4, Plasma...

Answer (score 2):

I'm presuming you are using Fedora Workstation. The desktop environment in Fedora Workstation is GNOME, which defaults to a "clean" desktop rather than one with icons — the idea is that you pin your favorites to the Dash rather than putting them on the desktop.

However, you *can* enable desktop icons using Tweak Tool. Use the Software app to install it if you don't have it already, and then run it. In the "Desktop" section, you should see a switch for "Icons on Desktop". Click that to "On", and there you go: icons on the desktop.

[image]

Comment: That didn't have any visible effect on my system. How would I know create a desktop shortcut for Chrome let's say?

Comment: Are you in X or Wayland?

Comment: Never mind, I was missing a `.desktop` file. It's working now. Also the desktop files need to have executable permission, otherwise icons don't work.